# How to subscribe after unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have an angular service with three attributes and two functions:

```
timerSubscription: Subscription;
pollingSubscription: Subscription;
incrementTimerSubscription: Subscription;

async startTimer(idTask: number) {
  this.timerSubscription = this.folderService
    .getTimerForTemplate(idTask)
    .pipe(
      tap(res => this.timer$.next(res.seconds)),
      switchMap(() => this.folderService.startTimerForTemplate(idTask))
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.setMyState({ idTask: idTask, isTimerStarted: true });

      this.incrementTimerSubscription = interval(1000)
        .pipe(
          tap(() => {
            this.timer$.next(this.timer$.value + 1);
          })
        )
        .subscribe();

      this.pollingSubscription = interval(20000)
        .pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            return this.folderService.incrementTimerForTemplate(idTask);
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    });
}

incrementAndStartTimer(idTaskToIncrement: number, idTaskToStart: number, automaticSwitch?: boolean) {
  if (this.timerSubscription) {
      this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.pollingSubscription) {
      this.pollingSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.incrementTimerSubscription) {
      this.incrementTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    if (automaticSwitch) {
      this.folderService
        .incrementTimerForTemplate(idTaskToIncrement, automaticSwitch)
        .pipe()
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.startTimer(idTaskToStart);
        });
    } else {
      this.folderService
        .incrementTimerForTemplate(idTaskToIncrement)
        .pipe()
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.startTimer(idTaskToStart);
        });
    }
}
```

When I invoke the startTimer function, it works well. However, after calling the incrementAndStart function, where I need to unsubscribe from existing subscriptions, I encounter an issue when trying to invoke the startTimer function again. I believe this is due to the previous subscriptions being unsubscribed. What could be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid to subscribe inside another subscribe().

`startTimer` doesn't need to be `async` you have no promise there. Remove `async`.

calling `.pipe()` makes no sense, remove it.
this can be simplified:

```
 if (this.timerSubscription) {
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
// simpler with ?. no need for an if 
this.timerSubscription?.unsubscribe();
```

what's the issue you encounter? have you debugged and see what code is called and here it stops? are there error logs?